# Overwriting global CSS style in modules is not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-modules

I'm having a problem with overwriting CSS styles using composing in modules.

My current setup:

- I have a thirdparty grid library file which I insert into my application in the entry JS file:

  ```
  import './css/thirdparty/file.css';
  ```
- I'm also using CSS modules for my components like this:

  ```
  import styles from './component.module.css';

  const Component = () => {

  // component code omitted

  // in render
  <div className={styles.col14}></div>
  ```
- In webpack config, I have two rules setup to load the `file.css` using plain `css-loader` and the `*.module.css` files using `css-loader` with modules.

All of these files are loaded correctly and the styles are all present. Here's the problem:

`file.css` contains:

```
.col-1-4 /* and all other col-1-* variations*/ {
    float: left;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.col-1-4 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

`component.module.css` contains:

```
.col14 {
    composes: col-1-4 from global;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Current output of the component:

```
<div class="col14__3bA8W col-1-4">
```

So the style is supposedly overwritten, but what I see in the browser is that the `padding-right` is still `20px`. It seems to only happen when I try to compose from a global style, because if I compose two classes from the same component CSS file, it works as expected.

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
.col14 {
  composes: col-1-4 from global;
  padding-right: 0!important;
}
```